# DNS Name compression for index > 16383

Tags: dns, standards, rfc

The DNS Name compression [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) (section 4.1.4) the 16-bit pointer contains a 14-bit OFFSET field that "specifies an offset from the start of the message" in place of a label. This allows pointers to reference labels within the first 16383 bytes of the packet, but with EDNS allowing packet sizes up to 65535 bytes, is there a way to point to names of index > 16383 ?

Comment: "The pointer takes the form of a two octet sequence:" 2 octets, that is 16 bits, minus the 2 fixed at value 1 at beginning, hence 14 bits, or 2^14 values that is 16384. How do you arrive at 4095? Then you may say that this is still short of 65535 but the idea is to compress names, that is labels "at the beginning" of a given record, not really data inside a record

Comment: Ah, my mistake, the maximum pointer value would be `0x3fff` or 16383, I was thinking `0x0fff`, I will edit it

Comment: Note that in the case you envision it means that "something" at position 16384 or later needs to reference the same name at another position before it (but still after 16384) and which name would never appear before  position 16384 which is certainly possible but quite improbable I would think. Remember again that this is only for **name** (label) compression not generic data compression

Comment: And to further back up my previous comment, see RFC3597 and specifically this phrase: *To avoid such corruption, servers MUST NOT compress domain names
   embedded in the RDATA of types that are class-specific or not well-
   known.  This requirement was stated in [RFC1123] without defining the
   term "well-known"; it is hereby specified that only the RR types
   defined in [RFC1035] are to be considered "well-known".* Being really still useful RFC1035 defines only: CNAME, MX, NS, PTR, SOA, TXT, A. So besides TXT I do not believe you can get the case your were thinking about.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek as it happens, I have actually encountered a case in which the answer section was so long that the authority section was after byte 16383, and the additional section was attempting to reference names in the authority section, which caused dig to throw a 'bad label' error

Comment: Are you sure that was not a decoding bug? Which bind version? Do you have the packet still maybe?

Comment: I am certain that it was not a decoding bug, I looked at the raw bytes of the packet and the pointer would have required 15 bits

Comment: Then the **generator** of this packet was broken.

Comment: Well how could it have done it better? There is no specified way of handling such large pointers, so how could it have done it any differently?

Comment: Name compression is optional (*Programs are free to avoid using pointers in messages they generate,
although this will reduce datagram capacity, and may cause truncation.
However all programs are required to understand arriving messages that
contain pointers.*), not mandatory. So do not compress if you can not express it in a valid pointer. Simple :-) Of course that packet from your description of it seems to be already off the chart length wise...

Comment: well, yeah perhaps the real problem is that it should have truncated it, but I suppose you are right that it didn't have to compress it

Comment: I doubt anyone writes DNS servers to handle such extreme edge cases, however

Comment: It certainly absolutely must not try to compress it in a way that violates the definition of a 14 bytes pointer...

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

**To answer your question, first there is no way to specify an offset greater than 2<sup>14</sup>-1 (16383), up to now**. The specifications could change in the future: some RFCs could be updated with some errata, they could be obsoleted by more recent ones, and even without changing the RFCs, a new label type could be added in the IANA registry of label types.

Secondly, even if there is not an absolute maximum payload size mentioned in the RFCs, the latest standards track RFC about DNS (RFC-6891) says that *a compromise may be the use of an EDNS maximum payload size of 4096*. Since 2<sup>14</sup> is much greater that 4096, this is not a problem.

**Explanations:**

The only way to get a new label type, for instance with a three octet sequence, is to register it into the DNS Label Types registry maintained by IANA, as stated in the latest standards track RFC that deals with label types: [RFC-6891](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6891). This is because this RFC deprecates the Extended Label Types registry introduced by RFC-2671 (RFC-6891 says: *There is therefore no Extended Label Types registry, with all label types registered in the DNS Label Types registry.*) So, there is only one registry: the DNS Label Types registry, that registers both standard label types **and** extended label types.

So, to check that a new label type exists, we only have to look at this IANA registry, that is officially maintained on the IANA web server: https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml

The section *DNS Label Types* in this registry has a table containing the only 6 **label types formats** that exist. Here are they:

- Normal label: lower 6 bits is the length of the label
- Compressed label: the lower 6 bits and the 8 bits from next octet form a pointer to the compression target
- Extended label type: the lower 6 bits of this type indicate the type of label in use
- Binary Label
- Reserved for future expansion
- Unallocated

Some are deprecated, some are proposed, but the only label types that are standards, according to the same document at IANA, are the Normal label and the Compressed label.

As you can see, there is not any other label type, extended or not, that can compress a domain name, with more flexibility than the "compressed label" type (the one that specifies an offset of 14 bits).

Comment: RFC6891 clearly warns: *Extended label types are extremely difficult to deploy due to lack of
   support in clients and intermediate gateways, as described in
   [RFC3363], which moved [RFC2673] to Experimental status; and
   [RFC3364], which describes the pros and cons.  As such, proposals
   that contemplate extended labels SHOULD weigh this deployment cost
   against the possibility of implementing functionality in other ways.*

Comment: Absolutely yes, and more over, many implementations like Internet boxes do not comply correctly to RFCs 1034/1035, so it is a very bad idea to change or extend such a critical part of the specs.